# JQuery: return div to initial height

Tags: jquery, height

I am trying to get a few divs to react to my mouseOver and mouseOut. I'm trying to build something similar to the the Vimeo-style volume bar.

I am getting the bars to react to the mouseOver, but I want them to return to their original height after the mouseOut. Each bar is a different height. It works when it is hard-coded, but I'm trying to use as little code as possible.

Here is my JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var totalHeight = '100%';
var initHeight;

function getHeight(h) {
  initHeight = h;
  //alert(initHeight);
}

$("div#barWrap").children().mouseover(function() {
    // This is where I am having trouble. I want to get the original height of the bar so I can reuse it on mouseOut
    getHeight($("div#barWrap").children().css('height')); 
    // Animate bar
    $(this).animate({ height: totalHeight}, 100);
});

$("div#barWrap").children().mouseout(function() {
    $(this).animate({ height: initHeight}, 400);
});
```

});

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the initial height as data for each element:

```
var totalHeight = '100%',
    $bwc = $('div#barWrap').children();

$bwc.each(function(i,el) {
    $(this).data('height', $(this).height());
});

$bwc.mouseover(function() {
    $(this).animate({ height: totalHeight}, 100);
});

$bwc.mouseout(function() {
    $(this).animate({ height: $(this).data('height') }, 400);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the data() function to store properties of your div: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use CSS transitions if you're able to target modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Put one div with `height:auto` into another with `overflow:hidden` and `height:0`, then after click, check inner div's height, and set the same to outer. Try it!

HTML:

```
<div id="visible-by-year" class="filter-visible">
    <div id="content"><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.filter-visible{
background: gray;
height: 0;
#content{
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

}

JS

```
  $('.by-year').on('click', function() {
     //$('.visible-by-year').toggleClass('show-by-year')
     //
    // $('#visible-by-year').animate({ height: $("#visible-by-year").data('height') }, 400);
     var contentHeight = $('#content').height();
     $('#visible-by-year').animate({ height: contentHeight}, 500 );

     console.log(contentHeight);


 });
```